# Tar complete vps server does not end - 24 hours

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, tar

I need to do a complete reinstall. On my VPS Ubuntu 16.04 i got the problem my backup process wont end.
I checked the data usage on my hard disk and the usual size is already backed up in less then a hour 20GB, after that each hour only 400-500Mb get archieved. 
It looks like there is some endless loop. 
The size before i started the tar command was 15Gb. Now the archieve is 30 Gb.

I did this command "tar cpzf filename.tar.gz /" in the main root as root user. I didnt use exclude for any folder in the mainroot or the archieve self wich is in the same directory.

Do i need to exclude a specific folder or the archieve self ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"tar cpzf filename.tar.gz /" in the main root* So you are creating the tar in the directory that the tar ought to contain... and the tar includes /dev...

Create the tar in a directory that you don't backup for instance in `/tmp` and give an explicit list of directories you want to copy (no need to backup /tmp, or even /boot, /proc, /dev....)

Comment: Thank you very much